# Generate percentage from based on values from other column using PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, percentage

I would like to create a new column which contains values as 50%,60% etc based on the values from the other columns present in the table. From the output shown below, I would like to have 'Desired Results' column based on values from 'cnt' column. Currently my input data is as shown below

[image]

I could only get the cnt of records from the query below. However I am not able to generate the percentage. Can you please help me?

```
with test as
(
select subject_id,hadm_id,case 
             when valuenum between 80 and 110 then 1
             else 0
             end as "within_range"
         from labevents where itemid in ('50809','50931','51529') and 
hadm_id is not null 


) select subject_id,hadm_id,within_range,count(*) as cnt
from test group by subject_id,hadm_id,within_range
```

I would like the output to be like as shown below

[image]

Comment: what is the logic behind those percentages

Comment: If you look at the data above, for subject_id = 3, has two rows and total cnt is 22, so 14/22 is 64 and 8/22 is 36. Similarly for the rest. For subjects where there is only one record, then it is 100 pc

Answer (score 1):

Use window function: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/

```
with cte as
     (
       select subject_id,
              hadm_id,
              case
                when valuenum between 80 and 110 then 1
                else 0
                end as "within_range"
         from labevents
        where itemid in ('50809', '50931', '51529')
          and hadm_id is not null
     ),
   subq as (
     select subject_id,
            hadm_id,
            within_range,
            count(*) as cnt
       from cte
      group by subject_id, hadm_id, within_range
   ) 
select subq.*, (cnt / sum(cnt) OVER (PARTITION BY subject_id, hadm_id)) * 100 "Desired Results" 
from subq;
```

Comment: For your logic you should adjust "PARTITION BY" columns

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function with the `group by`.  Also, the CTE is not really necessary, particularly because Postgres allows column aliases to be used for `group by`:

```
select subject_id, hadm_id,
       (case when valuenum between 80 and 110 then 1
             else 0
        end) as within_range,
       count(*) as cnt,
       count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as percentage
from labevents
where itemid in ('50809', '50931', '51529') and 
      hadm_id is not null 
group by subject_id, hadm_id, within_range
```

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you can have two subqueries where one being grouped by hadm_id and the other is not and join them both.

```
select a.* ,(a.cnt/b.cnt)*100 
from(select subject_id,hadm_id,within_range,count(*) as cnt
FROM (select subject_id,hadm_id,case 
             when valuenum between 80 and 110 then 1
             else 0
             end as "within_range"
         from labevents where itemid in ('50809','50931','51529') and 
hadm_id is not null) 
group by subject_id,hadm_id,within_range)a
INNER JOIN
(select subject_id,within_range,count(*) as cnt
FROM (select subject_id,hadm_id,case 
             when valuenum between 80 and 110 then 1
             else 0
             end as "within_range"
         from labevents where itemid in ('50809','50931','51529') and 
hadm_id is not null) 
group by subject_id,within_range)b
on a.subject_id,b.subject_id and a.within_range=b.within_range
```